# Insert a row from one DataTable in the middle of another DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable, insert, row

So, I have two DataTables. I can easly ADD rows from one to another with this:
`table1.Rows.Add(table2.Rows[0].ItemArray);`

But I want to insert the row in particular place, not on the bottom of the table1. Tried to use the `table1.Rows.InsertAt`, but the problem with it is that you need the DataRow class (which I can't figure out how to get), and also you can't do `table.Rows.InsertAt(table1.Rows[0], idex);` because it says that the row belongs to another table.
(table2 is source, table1 - target)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can clone the source row's items and then create a `DataRow` using them:

```
var sourceItems = (object[])(table2.Rows[0].ItemArray.Clone());

DataRow targetRow = table1.NewRow();
targetRow.ItemArray = sourceItems; 
table1.Rows.InsertAt(targetRow, index);
```

(note that it's not clear in your question which datatable is the source and which is the target, I assumed `table2` is the source and `table1` the target)